# Live streaming server in Node.js with RTMP URL

Tags: node.js, rtmp, live-streaming

How I can manage a RTMP URL streams from a NodeJs server

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you could write your own module in C/C++ and use it in node.js, however, the easy way is to use an existing node module from npm, as follow:

```
'use strict';

let videoStitch = require('video-stitch');

let videoMerge = videoStitch.merge;

videoMerge()
  .original({
    "fileName": "FILENAME",
    "duration": "hh:mm:ss"
  })
  .clips([
    {
      "startTime": "hh:mm:ss",
      "fileName": "FILENAME",
      "duration": "hh:mm:ss"
    },
    {
      "startTime": "hh:mm:ss",
      "fileName": "FILENAME",
      "duration": "hh:mm:ss"
    },
    {
      "startTime": "hh:mm:ss",
      "fileName": "FILENAME",
      "duration": "hh:mm:ss"
    }
  ])
  .merge()
  .then((outputFile) => {
    console.log('path to output file', outputFile);
  });
```

This is using a module called [video-stitch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-stitch).

I hope will be useful for you.